# Liferay publish structure id already existed

Tags: tomcat, liferay

When I try to publish a page from staging to live environment I receive this error:
"Fail to retrieve content" and in catalina.out I find "structure ID already exist".
I'm using liferay 6.1 with staging enabled.

Anyone know how I can force to change structure Id?

Tnx
Sabrina

Comment: This doesn't sound programming related. Webmasters maybe?

Comment: Can you please send the full stacktrace?

Comment: Have you checked the Liferay source code for where this error occurs to see the conditions that cause the error? I think forcing a change in Structure ID is probably not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a open bug of Liferay, see http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-25734

You can try to debug Liferay an fix the error self. Good luck!